# How to open an Excel Addin project from a Console Application project?

Tags: c#, excel, add-in

I have a Console Application project which opens a form. The same form has a button that should open an Excel file.

The solution is structured in 2 projects, the startup project is the console application and the other one is a Class Library that contains the Excel Addin and a Ribbon.

The thing is, I don't know how to start the excel when I press the button.

I added the reference of the Class Library to the References tab of my startup project.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If the file has already been created:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("C:\\test\\report.xlsx");
if(fi.Exists)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\test\report.xlsx");
}
else
{
    //file doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: The file does not exist yet.

Comment: Try this link: http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm